# Proper way to .findOne() in Iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Why is it that .findOne() does not work when executed inside the Router?
It always returns undefined.

Yet .find() works without any problems. Also tested .findOne() by manually entering the condition and the ._id manually.

Is .findOne() not designed to work inside the Router?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't. Can you show some code? It may be related to the old "the data hasn't arrive yet" issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's working properly in my application. I implemented it like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('training', {
        path: '/training/:id',
        data: function() {
            return Trainings.findOne({id: this.params.id});
        },
        notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
        title: "Training"
    });
});
```

Comment: I get that this works but what if I wanted to see the database result from the router itself? if I try to see the results of findOne inside the action: function() { } It will return undefined for some reason. But if I do .find() and try to see that data, it works. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

it works fine!
maybe you're trying to pass the result to an iterator? it's not a cursor. 
try a find().fetch() and use the result in the same way.

if it's a data/timing issue you could also guard with a ready() function.
you don't need to if you're using it reactively but this gives you a bit more explicit knowhow when things happen, yet without using a waitOn.

in coffeescript:

```
  #---------routes ---------
  @route 'routeName',
    path: '/path/to/:cname'
    onBeforeAction: ->
      Meteor.subscribe('Things', {
        cname: @params.cname
      })
      this.next()

    data: ->
      if @ready()
        data = {
          params: @params
        }
        data.lesson = Things.findOne({cname: @params.cname})
        return data
```